# Jmeter - concurrency thread group with throughput sample

Tags: jmeter

I have a JMeter test plan with a concurrency thread group and a throughput shaping timer.
below is a screenshot of the test plan.
[image]
The post requests are two requests which are sent one after another for a device. there should be 200 transactions/requests needs to sent per sec which I am controlling by target concurrency in concurrency thread group,  start RPS and end RPS in the throughput shaping timer.
the total TPS should be 200 ( sum of the first and second requests in the test plan) and the device would be different in each thread. can this be achieved with the above test plan. I see that post-event 2( second post-event in the test plan) are not sent for some of the devices towards the end of the test.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve the target throughput (RPS) with the Throughput Shaping Timer with the feedback function in the Concurrency Thread Group.

[image]

RPS can be set on the Throughput Shaping Timer

[image]

This [short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3wu69xwIPU) demonstrates the use of various options available in JMeter for Throughput Controlling.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, but be aware that "Concurrency" in the Concurrency Thread Group is the number of threads (virtual users) and the number of requests per second will be equal to the number of threads only if your application response time is 1 second.

If it's higher - you will need to proportionally increase the "Concurrency" in the Concurrency Thread Group.

More information: [What is the Relationship Between Users and Hits Per Second?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-relationship-between-users-and-hits-second)

You can connect Concurrency Thread Group with the Throughput Shaping Timer via [Feedback Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Use-With-Throughput-Shaping-Timer-Feedback-Function), this way JMeter will be able to kick off extra threads if the current amount is not sufficient in order to reach/maintain the desired amount of requests per second.

Also re-consider using listeners in your test plan, they don't add any value but just consume valuable resources, [you should be running JMeter tests in non-GUI mode with all listeners enabled/deleted](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean) and once test finishes open the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) with the listener of your choice or generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report)

Comment: At end of the test I see some of the requests from post event 2 is not been posted. how can I ensure the second request also gets completed with the test time ?

Comment: Concurrency Thread Group terminates virtual users when the time to hold the load is reached, there is no guarantee that both requests will be executed, if you need this - consider switching to the normal Thread Group and fixed number of loops. The number of requests per second can be still controlled with the Throughput Shaping Timer (or [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer/) or [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer))